# Shadow when I put a background image in a Button

Tags: java, android

My problem is that when I put a Button with an image in the background, a shadow appears. This is the code for the Sound Button

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton 
android:id="@+id/btn_atras"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginStart="16dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
android:background="@drawable/atras" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

PS: When I touch any of these button, the shadow makes like an effect, contracting the shadow.

```
[Back Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upQmm.png)
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo9RT.png)
[Sound Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHtln.png)
```

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVmNv.png)

I tried to change the style and put transparent background, nothing worked.

Comment: That's part of the default style that makes `Button`s look like `Button`s. If you just want flat, clickable images, you can use `ImageView`s instead, setting the drawable as `android:src` instead of `android:background`. If you really wanna stick with `Button`s, though, you can get rid of that shadow by setting `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`.

Comment: THANKS a lot. Works just like I wanted!